# "./configure" command does not work

Tags: compiling, configure, locate

I need to compile a package but the `./configure` command does not work?

I'm getting the following error:

> ```
> -bash ./configure : No such file or directory
> ```

Where is that script?

I used the `locate` command but it did not return anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`locate` will not work unless you have an up-to-date database.

Try `find . -type f -name configure` instead, or issue an `updatedb` command first, then do the `locate` (make sure the current path isn't excluded)

But first, you should always check the documentation - maybe the way to compile it does not use the `configure` mechanism in the first place.

Answer (score 8):

The 'configure' command is NOT a standard Linux/UNIX command.

`configure` is a script that is generally provided with the source of most standardized type Linux packages and contains code that will "patch" and localize the source distribution so that it will compile and load on your local Linux system.  Sometimes `configure` is put on your disk without the execute bit set, so the configuration could be invoked by `sh ./configure`....depending on the package, that is why they tell you to look at any type of `README` file.

Comment: Hi @mdpc, coming to this question with the same problem. If my distro doesn't have a `configure` command, do you know if there is any way to install it? Or do you have to do something else to install?

Comment: @Lou You don't *install* configure. `./configure` runs the script `configure` in your current working directory, and most standard packages provide one (for example, try cloning the Bash source code, then cd to the dir and run `./configure`) which prepares what is usually a Makefile.

Answer (score 1):

usually configure is in the top directory after you extracted the source of a package.

example:

```
mst@mst-gentoo-ws /tmp $ tar -xzf nginx-1.2.0.tar.gz 
mst@mst-gentoo-ws /tmp $ ls nginx-1.2.0/configure 
nginx-1.2.0/configure
```

so after unpacking, you have to cd into the newly created folder, and thats where `configure` should be.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot edit the question but want to share insights.

> I need to compile a package but the ./configure command does not work?

The compilation configuration may differ and you should always look for /readme.*/i (case-insensitive) or something related COMPILE.md

> I'm getting the following error:
>
> -bash ./configure : No such file or directory
> Where is that script?

It could be not existing. Maybe the project is build different way, if you i.e. have .sh extension which is simply the issue.
I would not suggest find, but first `ls -a` directory, or if you have no idea how it is called (case: no idea how this project works, not have documentation you could refer to also) you could look for `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh` in all files with `grep`:

`grep  -Enr '#!\/bin\/(ba){0,1}sh'`
It uses regex `-E`, goes recursively down all subdirectories `-r`, return name and the line, so could be inefficient.
In case project is "strange" (not have standard configuration and compilation procedure) then you might want use it.